# cross platform software to convert video to image sequence

Tags: video, formats, transcoding

I'm looking for a piece of software I'm even sure it exists.
Here's what I would like this software to do:

- be free (ideally open source, but free and closed source is also fine)
- be cross platform (at least works on Win and OSX, Linux support would be nice)
- import a variety of video formats (mov, avi, wmv, mpg, mp4, ogg, flv, 3gp, etc.)
- exports an image sequence from the imported video

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). It will run on just about anything and should do what you want, although it might depend on what your source actually is
Something like this should work :

```
ffmpeg -i sourcefile.avi -f image2 'img-%03d.jpeg'
```

(see the [image2 section](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#image2-2) for full reference)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have look. The main purpose is to have this software running on the average user's machine. I'll have look to see if I can bundle it and put a minimal gui on top.

Comment: If you want GUI you might want to check VLC, it's using some of the same libraries too

Answer (score 4):

For a good GUI based on libavcodec (which a ffmpeg library), take a look at [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/screenshots.php). Might be a bit too detailed for a very "simple" user, but with some effort it's manegable. It also supports saving of presets, so you can set it up for easy use.